# save post from file into msword

Tags: php, html

i want to save a post from an html form into a msword file

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <text name="comment"></text>
   <input type="submit" name="send" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
    $body=$_POST['comment'];
    $newfile = fopen("essay/last.docx", "w") ;
   $content = "$body";
   fwrite($newfile, $content);

  fclose($newfile);
}
?>
```

the created file is not a valid msword file. any help is appreciated

Comment: *"the created file is not a valid msword file"* ... that's not terribly surprising since `.docx` is a form of XML, [Office Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh643329(v=office.12).aspx) - you'll probably want [some sort of library](https://www.phpdocx.com/) to insert the text/plain form data into the docx.

Comment: As mentioned simply saving text as `.docx` doesn't turn it into a word document. Quick fix would be to save it as a `.txt` instead and use notepad(++) to open it, you'd have the content just not in word.